# CakePHP and PHP 5.4 Bult-In Web Server: wrong URL request (404 Error)

Tags: php, cakephp, http-status-code-404

I was testing CakePHP 2.1.2 with the bult-in PHP 5.4 web server and found a problem: I didn't change any .htaccess, but there's wrong URL request, which is causing 404 Error.

I am starting the PHP 5.4 server at /app/webroot:

```
$ php -S localhost:8080
```

The request to the index (http://localhost:8080) is OK, everything works fine. But when I access some controller/action (http://localhost:8080//sections/about/, in my case) the texto is shown ok, but the requests to resources (css, js and images) fail.

Here are some logs of the server:

When requesting the index:
...

When requesting a controller/action:
...

The prefix of the request to "css/style.css" must be "/", but it's beeing sent "/index.php/sections/"

The .htaccess of /app/webroot is (the CakePHP default .htaccess):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Anyone knows the solution?

Comment: I've had similar problems when by accident double slashed appeared in my URL, just like in yours: http://localhost:8080//sections/about/

Answer (score 3):

The built-in server **does not support** .htaccess files.

You should switch off Url Rewriting in Cakephp, at least on development.

Maybe, on the hacking side, you can find joy with [jaytaph HtRouter project](https://github.com/jaytaph/htrouter) who claims to be "a PHP 5.4 Internal Webserver .htaccess parser and interpreter."

Hope this helps !

Comment: To disable the Rewrite works well. I think I will turn off the rewrite in development environment. But the bult-in server supports .htaccess. I made some simple tests and it worked fine. Maybe the support is partial, or there are some restrictions. Anyway, thanks for your answer :)